# Write password to console with tty-command gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using this [gem](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-command) to run `git clone` but it asks me to type the password, I need to know the right way to do this

i'm trying this [way](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-command#322-handling-input) but it's not working

```
in_stream = StringIO.new
in_stream.puts "password"
in_stream.rewind

cmd = TTY::Command.new
git_clone = "git clone https://user@bitbucket.org/repository.git '/home/user/aplication/my-project'"
cmd.run(git_clone, in: in_stream).out
```

I get this error

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://user@bitbucket.org': Device or address does not exist
```

**How can i fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

This is totally the wrong way of going about this IMO. Use a tool built for the job. Use an actual git library for Ruby like [ruby-git](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git).